# Operator overload for vector function c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm sure this question is super simple, I'm just quite new to programming and to C++ in general.

For my class, we are making a Vector with a class template. My professor has supplied the .h file and we have to write the integrated .cpp file. Heres the .h file:

```cpp
#ifndef SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#define SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <new> // Needed for bad-alloc exception
#include <cstdlib> // Needed for the exit function
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SimpleVector
 {
        private:
                T *aptr;                         // To point to the allocated array
                int arraysize;                   // Number of elements in the array
                void memError();                 // Handles memory allocation errors
                void subError();                 // Handles subscripts out of range


        public:
        SimpleVector()
                {
                aptr = 0;
                arraysize = 0;
                }
        SimpleVector(int s);
        SimpleVector(const SimpleVector & sv);
        ~SimpleVector();
        int size() const
                {
                return arraysize;
                }
        T getElementAt(int sub);
        T &operator[](const int);


};

#endif //SIMPLEVECTOR_H
```

And here is my implementation:

```cpp
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int s)
{
        if(s<1)
        {
        arraysize=1;
        }
        else
        {
        arraysize=s;
        }

        try
        {
        aptr = new T [arraysize];
        }

        catch (bad_alloc)
        {
        memError();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
        {
        aptr[i]=0;
        }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::memError()
{

        cout<<"Error: cannot allocate memory."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::memError()
{

        cout<<"Error: cannot allocate memory."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
T SimpleVector<T>::getElementAt(int sub)
{
        return aptr[sub];
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::~SimpleVector()
{
        delete aptr;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::subError()
{

        cout<<"Subscripts out of range."<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(const SimpleVector & sv)
{
        aptr=sv.aptr;
}

template <class T>
T<T>&::operator[](const int &)
{
        return aptr[];
}
```

I know that my overload operator is way off and makes no sense, I just dont understand the syntax well enough to even know where to begin. Obvisouly, the operator should return the value of the `aptr` at whatever index was passed in through `[]`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Check page - 647 at http://www.stroustrup.com/PPP2_Ch18.pdf

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Comment: "Obvisouly, the operator should return the value of the aptr at whatever index was passed in through []." Correct. So why don't you do exactly that? It's as easy as you described it. Or are you irritated because the function declaration forgot to mention the name of the passed parameter (`T& operator(const int index)` - just a `const int` not a `const int &` as you implemented it!)?

Answer (score 0):

There are *multiple* problems with your code, including:

- Not catching `bad_alloc` correctly (never catch an exception class by value, always by reference).
- duplicate definitions of `memError()`. You need to remove one of them.
- `~SimpleVector()` using `delete` instead of `delete[]`.
- `SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &)` making a *shallow* copy of `sv.aptr` when it needs to make a *deep* copy instead.
- `getElementAt()` not calling `subError()` if `sub` is out of range. Historically, `operator[]` doesn't perform range checking, but you can if you want/need to.

But, to answer the specific question you asked, your `operator[]` is implemented all wrong. Aside from the obvious syntax error in writing its definition, and that the definition does not match the declaration, internally it simply needs to do the same `return` action that the `getElementAt()` method is doing, eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
T& SimpleVector<T>::operator[](const int sub)
{
    return aptr[sub];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your comments! I'm definitely aware the code is absolute garbage. Is there anyway you could expand more on the memError and subError, I've never actually implemented things like that, and I don't really understand them.